# Scraping dynamic webpages with nightmare (PhantomJS) on NodeJS takes way too long. How can I make this process faster?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, electron, phantomjs, nightmare

Here is my code snippet:

```
       nightmare
  .goto('https://www.stadiumgoods.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=BV4594-001')
  .wait('body')
  .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('body').innerHTML)
  .end()
  .then(response => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response);

    console.log($('.item > a').attr('href'));
```

This snippet grabs the URL of the first product that shows up on the link. However, this process takes a whole 30 seconds to just grab the link.

Is there any way of making this process faster? Maybe using another npm package other than nightmare? I've tried using puppeteer but it won't work on this specific website for me.

Comment: It basically starts a headless browser then opens the page there to render. So it will take time and also it depends on the network and pc speed also. Check out [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) if it improves anything.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest doing is the following:

- Try with Puppeteer again as the conversion from nightmare to Puppeteer is not a hard task
- Block CSS and Images from loading with the following code:

  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on('request', (req) => {
      if(req.resourceType() == 'stylesheet' || req.resourceType() == 'font' || req.resourceType() == 'image'){
          req.abort();
      }
      else {
          req.continue();
      }
  });

Ultimately, like the other comment mentioned: It also depends on the network speed and the power of the server / pc that the script is being ran on.

Cheers!